# Prove that the following set $A=\{2n−1∥ n∈N\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> A subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is complete if every Cauchy sequence consisting of elements of S converges to an element of S

Prove that the following set $A=\{2n−1∥ n∈N\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is complete.

**Note:** I don't want the solution (at least not eight now) but I want to run past people my idea of how to prove this.

**IDEA:**

So we stated in class as an example without proof that $\mathbb{N}$ is complete by way of it being closed. But the professor stressed to us to try and show this set is complete without using the fact about $\mathbb{N}$.

So after playing around with this set I've noticed that it "appears" that the only convergent sequences are sequences of a specific constant term. That being the case, since $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ this would also mean that these sequences are Cauchy. Now if these are the ONLY convergent sequences of this then I could show that these sequences converge to an element of my set $A=\{2n−1∥ n∈N\}$

**Here is my issue with this:** Saying that this is the only convergent sequence AND the only Cauchy sequence for a countably infinite set is a pretty damn bold statement. Even though it appears to be the case from playing around how could I show that to be true and also is my idea towards showing the set is complete correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** A sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $A$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0 \, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N \, \forall n, m \geq n_0: \vert x_n - x_m \vert < \epsilon. $$ 
So take $\epsilon = 1$ for example. What can you say about a sequence the that suffices the assertion above for that explicit $\epsilon$? How does it relate to your observation? :)

Comment: well based on the Cauchy definition you wrote and along with the elements of my set. IF I were to choose even two elements that were beside each other (e.g. $2n -1$ and $2(n+1) - 1)$ I would get a distance $2 > \epsilon$. The only way to satisfy $\epsilon = 1$ would be to pick a constant sequence.

Comment: Indeed, such sequences are constant except for finitely many elements of the sequence. Notice, the sequence doesn' need to be constant for all indices! But what can you say now about this almost constant sequence and its limit? :)

Comment: I agree I was thinking of other sorts of sequences but eventually the only way I could satisfy the $\epsilon$ condition of Cauchy would be to end up becoming a constant sequence.Well i can say that these almost constant sequences converge and their limit is going to be whatever constant the tail of the sequence becomes. Ok I see this, but how do I eliminate the "possibility" of this not being true? i.e: how would I make it a sound proof?

Comment: Essentially, Raul Fierro wrote this idea down above rigidly. And if you check it carefully, you will see it is basicly just that argument you gave :)

Comment: I saw that...is it? I mean how are we able to make the jump from $|x_n - x_m|< 1 \rightarrow x_n = x_m$ ? ...I don't disagree with it.....I'm just curious how it plays out logically... EDIT: I think I see why. By the fact of how our terms are defined in the set, the only possible way the $\epsilon$ condition is satisfied is by $x_n = x_m$ so it is by keeping in mind what my elements of the set are that allows me to draw that conclusion.

Comment: From the definition of $A$ we know that if $x, y \in A$ with $x \neq y$ we always have $\vert x - y \vert \geq 2$ (draw it maybe). So if we have $x, y \in A$ with $\vert x - y \vert < 2$ this has to imply that $x = y$.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Yaddle

Answer (score 3):

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $A$. Hence, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<1$, whenever $m,n\geq n_0$. In particular, $|x_n-x_{n_0}|<1$ for all $n\geq n_0$. This means that $x_n=x_{n_0}$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Therefore, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x_{n_0} \in A$ and, consequently, $A$ is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply the definition of Cauchy sequence to $\epsilon=2$, for example.

Comment: I guess that would then imply that since it is Cauchy that a limit does exist, we just don't know what that limit is.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a cauchy sequence of points from $S$, and $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, there is no question as to whether the sequence converges, it certainly converges, the question is whether it converges to something in $S$.

What the other answers are hinting at, is that if you satisfy the cauchy property, then this means that at some $N$, you have $|s_n - s_m| < \epsilon$ for $n,m >N$. But since $s_n \in S$ and $s_m \in S$, they are of the form $$s_n = 2p+1$$ $$s_m = 2q+1 $$

for some $p,q$, but $|s_n - s_m| < \epsilon$ impies $p = q$ for many of the epsilons in the other answers. So for all but finitely many $n$'s, specifically for all but those $n$ with $n<N$,  $$s_n = s_m \to s = 2p+1$$
for some $p$, and $s\in A$